# imagemagick pdf to jpg - font quality bad

Tags: php, imagemagick, ghostscript

I do upload PDFs to PHP and extract the pages as JPG in different resolutions in a kind of batch through JS + AJAX-Calls to work arround PHP timeout.

But the font is rendering not so pretty... what can I do?

```
$pdf = new Imagick();
$pdf->setresolution(225, 225);
$pdf->readimage('mypdf[0-5]');
$written = $pdf->writeimages('previewfolder/pages/hq-0.jpg', FALSE);
$pdf->clear();
$pdf->destroy();
```

I tryed upsetting the values of `setresolution` to `500`and `500`, then the font is a Little bit better but the Image is also much bigger in Resolution. Here an screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei9rl.jpg

My Target: small Image (1000px*1000px) but with as max font-quality as possible.

Hopefully someone has an Idea.

Regards, lippoliv

Comment: If you want quality, don't use JPEG. The filtering of JPEG causes high frequency features to 'ring'. Any abrupt changes (such as text) will suffer from this. If you want text quality and low size, use a lossless compression method, such as Flate. Try using PNG output.

Comment: Is it the right font, or different?

Comment: the font itself is correct. just the Quality of the font is bad. the Images have no bad Quality, so JPEG should be ok!? I will test PNG.

Comment: JPEG is designed for photographic images (Joint Photographic Experts Group), where features tend not to have high resolution components. Its not appropriate for use with (eg) text, monochrome bitmaps, scanned documents (except when those are photographs) etc. The point of JPEG is that it achieves its compression by throwing away data, its a 'lossy' format. The idea is to throw away data that doesn't make much difference to human perception. Abrupt changes (like text) don't work well with this.

Comment: What I define as "ugly": http://imgur.com/5U88bx5, that is a screenshot from PNG, it doesn't help to Switch from JPG to PNG...

Comment: Set the resolution to 300,300, or higher, before reading the image, then after reading the image, resize it to 1000x1000 with `resizeImage()`

Comment: Hey Mark Setchell, thanks for reply :) Like this? http://pastebin.com/X7ug85TY It results in an 1.200*800px Image. Nothing changed on the letters :/

Comment: Could it possibly be, that I do something wrong? For testing purposes I used resizeimage (see my pastebin-link) with 100*100, and the resulting Image also is 1.200 * 800px...

Answer (score 1):

as often: mistake 40 (the mistakes sits 40cm in front of his Monitor)...

```
$pdf = new Imagick();
$pdf->setresolution(350, 350);
$pdf->readimage('mypdf[0-5]');

// Because we have multiple pages, we have to process each page.
foreach ($pdf as $page) {
    $page->resizeimage(1500, 1500, \Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1.1, TRUE);
}

$written = $pdf->writeimages('previewfolder/pages/hq-0.jpg', FALSE);
$pdf->clear();
$pdf->destroy();
```

Thanks to Mark Setchell who brought in that Idea and made me thinking about why the resize doesn't work. And than ofter another hour of Google I found an example about resizeing Images, pointing out that you have to resize each Frame.

So I thought may I have to resize each single page of my PDF (in that example there are 6 pages) and now it works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DH3J.jpg

Now I can up- / downscale the Image size as I like to and get nice Fonts :) Even as a JPG.

Thank you all.